# Does every get<Something> request on a CalendarApp object correspond to one HTTP request/API call?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Using Apps Script and Google's CalendarApp, I'm trying to get all the events from two calendars for two days (today + tomorrow) and sort them by start time.

I'm currently doing this like this:

```
// Function passed to sort() later to compare two calendar events
function compareEvents(event1, event2) {
  if (event1.getStartTime().getTime() === event2.getStartTime().getTime())
    return 0;
  if (event1.getStartTime() < event2.getStartTime())
    return -1;
  return 1;
}

// Main function
function getEventsAndSortThem() {
  var cal1 = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('<Name 1 here>')[0];
  var cal2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarsByName('<Name 2 here>')[0];
  var events = []

  var today = new Date();
  var tomorrow = new Date(today.getTime() + 1*24*3600*1000);

  var cal1Events = cal1.getEvents(today, tomorrow); // Get events for two days
  var cal2Events = cal2.getEvents(today, tomorrow); // Get events for two days

  for (var i in cal1Events)
    events.push(cal1Events[i]);

  for (var i in cal2Events)
    events.push(cal2Events[i]);

  //Sort using compareEvents
  events.sort(compareEvents);

  for (var i in events) {
    var event = events[i];
    Logger.log(event.getStartTime()+" ["+event.getTitle()+"]");
  }
}
```

Is this the most efficient way of doing this? In the compareEvents function, does each getStartTime() make a new HTTP request?

Or is it the case that when I use getEvents() to get the events from the calendars, all the data related to the events is returned and the subsequent getStartTime()s are processed locally without the need for a new API call?

Would it be more efficient to save the fields I want from the events to my own custom object and perform any subsequent processing using that?